# Imprimir solo vocales de una palabra

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa que pide un nombre o frase, luego el programa solo imprimirá las vocales nada más. Tengo una mínima idea de como es, con un bucle `for` y `if` luego se añade a una lista vacía o cadena, y actualmente el programa que tengo es este:

```
frase = input("Frase: ")

vocales = 'aeiou'

a = ''

for x in frase:
    if vocales in frase:
        a += str(vocales)

print(a)
```

El programa no me funciona nada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero hay que recorrer la frase con `for x in frase`. Eso devuelve letra a letra.

Luego preguntas si la letra está entre las vocales con `if x in vocales`. En tal caso, la agregas a la variable de salida.

```
frase = input("Frase: ")
vocales = 'aeiou'
a = ''
for x in frase:
    if x in vocales:
        a += x

print(a)
```

Produce:

```
Frase: la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta
aoaaiaeaueouaia
```

**Solución pythonica**

La anterior es una solución pedestre. Con Python podemos usar compresión de lista:

```
frase = input("Frase: ")
vocales = 'aeiou'
a = "".join([x for x in frase if x in vocales])

print(a)
```

La parte `[x for x in frase]` forma una lista con todas las letras de la frase, pero como solo nos interesan las vocales, agregamos una condición:

```
[x for x in frase if x in vocales]
```

lo que nos da esta lista:

```
['a', 'o', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'u', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'a', 'i', 'a']
```

Con `join` tomamos los elementos de la lista y los concatenamos. Hay que indicar una cadena que se insertara entre elemento y elemento. No queremos insertar nada; especificamos una cadena vacia:

```
"".join([x for x in frase if x in vocales])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
contador = 0
while i < len(palabra1):
    if palabra1[i] == VOCALES:
        Contador = Contador + 1
    i = i + 1
```

con esto cuentas las vocales puede pedir un print (contador) y entragara tu respuesta

Comment: Pero esto no es lo que se pide en la pregunta, recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)