# Imprimir solo las vocales en mayusculas de una palabra python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un programa que pide una palabra, luego solo imprimira de vuelta la misma frase pero con las vocales en mayusculas, de momento la idea es recorrer la palabra luego identificar si es vocal y uppear luego imprimir toda la frase pero no tengo ni idea

```
frase = input("Frase: ")

vocales = 'aeiou'

a = ''

for x in frase:
    if vocales in frase:
        a.upper()
    else:
        a.lower()
```

print(a)

El resultado seria: input hola output hOlA

ya cambie ahora no da nada directamente

Comment: ¿Por qué usas el mismo código que en la otra pregunta? [Imprimir solo vocales de una palabra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400083/imprimir-solo-vocales-de-una-palabra). Ya tienes una respuesta que cubre el 90% de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma, obteniendo la cadena e iterando cada caracter verificando si esta es vocal la conviertes en mayúscula con `upper()`,

```
def obtieneFraseVocalesMayusculas(frase):
    frasefinal = ""
    for char in frase:
        if char in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
            char = char.upper()
            frasefinal += char
        else: 
            frasefinal += char
    return frasefinal 

frase = input("Frase: ")

print(obtieneFraseVocalesMayusculas(frase))
```

Ejemplo

```
Frase: hola Alvarog
```

salida:

```
hOlA AlvArOg
```

---

Si no deseas hacer uso de una función, esta sería la forma:

```
frase = input("Frase: ")
frasefinal = ""
for char in frase:
    if char in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        char = char.upper()
        frasefinal += char
    else: 
        frasefinal += char

print(frasefinal)
```

Comment: Hay alguna forma sin tener que usar una funcion?

Comment: Si, claro, agrego la actualización a la respuesta.

Comment: Bueno no hace falta ya me funciono gracias

Comment: Ok @Alvarog de cualquier forma lo agregué, saludos.